# Find the limit of the following

Tags: analysis, limits

$$
  \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left( e^{\sin x} + e^{\frac{1}{\sin x}} \right).
$$
Hi all, which method would I used to solve this type of limit??

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the way $x$ approaches $0$?

Comment: no that is all that was given

Comment: Then the limit doesn't exist, as seen in Michael T's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Observe the left hand limit and the right hand limit. We have $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{\sin x} = -\infty$ while $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sin x} = \infty$